# coldfusion xor translated from java

Tags: java, coldfusion, xor

I have this loop in java :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
   data[i] ^= INIT_VECTOR[i];
}
```

when trying to translate to coldfusion :

```
<cfscript>
    for ( i = 1; i < 17; i++) {
      data[i] = data[i] XOR INIT_VECTOR[i];
    }
</cfscript>
```

it throws the following error :

```
You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class [B as structure with members
```

please tell me what was my mistake ?

thanks.

Comment: In CF, what are the definitions of `data` and `INIT_VECTOR`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As QuantumMechanic comments, need to see how the two arrays are created. It is very easy to duplicate that error by simply declaring the arrays wrong like `<cfset data = "ArrayNew(1)" />` instead of the correct syntax of `<cfset data = ArrayNew(1) />`.

Also, instead of using the XOR operator, you might want to use the BitXor function instead. When I tested this, XOR returned a CF boolean value of yes/no and you probably just want the bit which BitXor will return.

```
<cfscript>
    for (i=1; i<17; i++) {
        data[i] = BitXor(data[i], INIT_VECTOR[i]);
    }
</cfscript>
```